# How to set value input text Array with Javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to calculate the result of the gap from (target - current), to know the result of each competency gap. All Compentencies have different targets, and I write this JavaScript function to calculate the results of the gap:

```js
function targetCA() {
  var target = parseInt(document.getElementById("targ_a").value);
  var current = parseInt(document.getElementById("curre_a").value);

  var total = current - target;

  document.getElementById('gap_a').value = total;


}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>Compentency</td>
    <td>Target</td>
    <td>Current</td>
    <td>Gap</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Operating Computer</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="targ_a" name="targ_a[]" id="targ_a" onchange="targetCA();" value="" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="curre_a[]" id="curre_a" class="curre_a" onchange="targetCA();" value="" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gap_a[]" id="gap_a" class="gap_a" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Operating Microsoft Excel</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="targ_a" name="targ_a[]" id="targ_a" value="" onchange="targetCA();" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="curre_a[]" id="curre_a" class="curre_a" onchange="targetCA();" value="" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gap_a[]" id="gap_a" class="gap_a" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But when counting only the first line can be counted.

I do not know how to make each line count properly.

I do not know how to calculate the input type array with javascript.

Maybe someone can help me to solve this problem. Thanks Very Much

Comment: In General, Html element id cannot be repeated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is you have same `id`s for element. ID should be unique. If you have duplicate IDs, it will always fetch the first element with necessary id.

Instead, try to parse based on row. Pass row number and then fetch necessary element using `name` or `class` attribute.

```js
function targetCA(rowNumber) {
  var table = document.getElementById('tblData');
  var row = table.querySelectorAll('tr')[rowNumber];

  var target = parseInt(row.querySelector("input[name='targ_a[]']").value || 0);
  var current = parseInt(row.querySelector("input[name='curre_a[]']").value || 0);

  var total = current - target;

  row.querySelector('input[name="gap_a[]"]').value = total;


}
```

```html
<table border='1' id='tblData'>
  <tr>
    <td>Compentency</td>
    <td>Target</td>
    <td>Current</td>
    <td>Gap</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Operating Computer</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="targ_a" name="targ_a[]" id="targ_a" onchange="targetCA(1);" value="" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="curre_a[]" id="curre_a" class="curre_a" onchange="targetCA(1);" value="" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gap_a[]" id="gap_a" class="gap_a" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Operating Microsoft Excel</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="targ_a" name="targ_a[]" id="targ_a" value="" onchange="targetCA(2);" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="curre_a[]" id="curre_a" class="curre_a" onchange="targetCA(2);" value="" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gap_a[]" id="gap_a" class="gap_a" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Alternate approach**

- Create a init function that will register event dynamically.
- Navigate to parent `tr`
- Fetch inputs and perform calculation

```js
function targetCA() {
  var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;

  var target = parseInt(row.querySelector("input[name='targ_a[]']").value || 0);
  var current = parseInt(row.querySelector("input[name='curre_a[]']").value || 0);

  var total = current - target;

  row.querySelector('input[name="gap_a[]"]').value = total;
}

function registerEvents() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#tblData input[type="number"]');
  
  for(var i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', targetCA)
  }
}

registerEvents();
```

```html
<table border='1' id='tblData'>
  <tr>
    <td>Compentency</td>
    <td>Target</td>
    <td>Current</td>
    <td>Gap</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Operating Computer</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="targ_a" name="targ_a[]" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="curre_a[]" class="curre_a" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gap_a[]" class="gap_a" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Operating Microsoft Excel</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="targ_a" name="targ_a[]" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="curre_a[]" class="curre_a" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gap_a[]" class="gap_a" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I use Alternate approach, This way is work Well. Thank you very Much

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what you did wrong is you defined same exact ids for different elements. Ids are meant to be unique. If you define deffierent ids then use them in your method it should be fine.

Like this:

```
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>Compentency</td>
    <td>Target</td>
    <td>Current</td>
    <td>Gap</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Operating Computer</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="targ_a" name="targ_a[]" id="targ_a" onchange="targetCA();" value="" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="curre_a[]" id="curre_a" class="curre_a" onchange="targetCA();" value="" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gap_a[]" id="gap_a" class="gap_a" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Operating Microsoft Excel</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="targ_a" name="targ_a[]" id="targ_b" value="" onchange="targetCA();" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="curre_a[]" id="curre_b" class="curre_a" onchange="targetCA();" value="" placeholder="0">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gap_a[]" id="gap_b" class="gap_a" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
function targetCA() {

  var charArray = ['a','b'];

  for (var i=0; i<charArray.length;i++){


    var target = parseInt(document.getElementById("targ_"+charArray[i]).value);
    var current = parseInt(document.getElementById("curre_"+charArray[i]).value);

    var total = current - target;

    document.getElementById('gap_'+charArray[i]).value = total;

  }


}
```

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can create a snippet using it

Comment: I use the same ids, because later the text input will be in looping from the database